# What is the substitution of hash in NSObject in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsobject

I found that the hash method is deprecated in NSObject in iOS8 (Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 7.1), I use hash combine with isEqual normally, what's the substitution of hash in iOS8, what should I do now in iOS8？Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out "`hash`" has become a read-only `property` of a base NSObject.

Along with a few other "methods", including `superclass`, `description` and `debugDescription`.

Not sure what Apple was thinking behind this (and I don't see any info about this in the documentation, .h files or devforums), but [more information can be found here](http://www.redwindsoftware.com/blog/post/2014/08/20/NSObject-has-some-new-properties-in-iOS-8.aspx).

Comment: I know iOS 8 brought MANY similar changes to many classes. Many old setter/getter methods were changed to properties. The effective API is the same though. It's odd that the documentation for the `NSObject` protocol is confusing about `hash` being deprecated.

Comment: would have been nice if the docs actually mentioned these deprecated methods are actually now properties.

Comment: Agreed. There is a link at the bottom of every page in the docs to submit feedback. Seems like a good candidate.

Comment: A big reason for this method to property transition all through iOS and OS X was interoperability with Swift.